# Blocked threads in getBeanFactory

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, amazon-ec2

I have a high throughput server, running with spring IOC (2.5.6) on Amazon EC2 (Virginia). In the past few days I didn't do any changed in the code (only some configuration changes), but suddenly I started seeing crazy locking issue with spring. The application seem to spend 60%-80% of it's time trying to get beans (different beans, from different areas of the code), and a thread dump shows most threads are stuck in the following manner:

```
Thread 15148: (state = BLOCKED)
 - org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory() @bci=6, line=151 (Compiled frame)
 - org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(java.lang.String) @bci=1, line=880 (Compiled frame)
```

Our application is very IO intensive, so I expect to see most of the time spent on database connections and HTTP client access. 
I'm not sure which additional information I can provide here.

Anyone seen something of that sort?